# How do I call a function into another code file without getting error messages; and how to compare dictionaries to lists?

Tags: python, function

I am making an online grocery store as a homework assignment. I have successfully created the dictionaries of items including their stock and price from a text file. We have to create input statements where the users tell us what they want and how many. Then we have to create two functions in a separate python script.

I am concerned about Function 1 The purpose of this function is to:

- Loop through the items in the groc_list (which I have created)
- Pull the unit price of each item from the prices dictionary
- Check the stock of the items in the stock dictionary versus the number of items selected in the unit_list.

If there are not enough items in stock, we have to respond to the user accordingly.

The function should update the stock dictionary to show a reduction in the total stock.  (e.g. if the shopper selects 2 gallons of milk, the stock dictionary key – “milk” should have its value decreased by 2).

I continue to get an error code about my arguments in the main code and one about a "list" item not being callable in my function code. I cannot figure it out.

I am omitting the first part of the code where I create the dictionaries and what not. In this code, I get an error when I try to call the function with its arguments. I simply gives a regular 'error'

```
#code for main grocery store
#empty user shopping list
groc_list=[]
unit_list=[]

while 'done' not in groc_list:
    groc_item=input('\nType the grocery item you would like to purchase.\If you are done shopping, type done: ')
    groc_list.append(groc_item)
    if groc_item == 'done':
        print('Thanks for shopping')

    #asks user quantity
    elif groc_item in stock.keys():
        unit_quan=input('How many would you like? ')
        unit_list.append(unit_quan)

    else:
        print('We are sorry. We do not recognize that item.\Please check your spelling.')

# removes 'done' 
groc_list.pop()

# function 1
from grocery import grocery_cost
grocery_cost(groc_list, prices, stock, unit_list)
```

In the function, I run into trouble when it goes to the 'elif' part of the statement. It says 'list' item is not callable. I think all my numbers are set as integers.

```
#The code for function 1
def grocery_cost(groc_list, prices, stock, unit_list):
    """Checks stock of items vs items customer selects. Prints if item is unavailable"""

    count=0
    for item in groc_list:
        if stock[item] == 0:
            print('We are sorry. We are out of stock of that item, \
                    and it will not be added to your cart.')

        elif stock[item] >= unit_list(count):
            y=unit_list(count)*prices[item]
            print('%s %15.2f \n' %(item, y))
            stock[item]=stock[item]-unit_list(count)

        else:
            print('Only', stock[item], ' of that item is available. \
                    Those have been added to your cart.')
            y=stock[item]*prices[item]
            unit_list.pop(count)
            unit_list.insert(count, stock[item])
            print('%s %15.2f \n' %(item, y))
            stock[item]=stock[item]-unit_list(count)

        count+=1

        return y
```

I expected the program to calculate my totals for each item and allow me to take the returned value from the function and use it in my code, but instead, it quits.

Comment: To acess a function from a seperate file,  you should create a class object and then import it from the file.

Answer (score 1):

unit_list(count) should be unit_list[count]
Try it, please!

Comment: I tried that and it changed my error to say that '>=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'.

Comment: I had an input coming in as a string instead of an integer. Your solution helped. Thank you!!

Comment: You can test their respective types. eg. type(stock[item]) & type(unit_list[count])

Comment: then change it to the same type. eg. int(..) or str(..)